# Why os.Open returns nil error when opening a directory?

Tags: linux, go

I've spend some time looking for an error in my code and it appeared that at one place I was trying to read contents of a directory like it was the file. Consider the following code:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func init() {
    file, err := os.Open("/tmp/")
    fmt.Println(file, err) //err == nil here
    var b []byte
    n, err := file.Read(b)
    fmt.Println(n, err) //err == "read /tmp/: is a directory"
}
```

I am wondering, why `os.Open` allows to 'open' a directory without an error if I cannot 'read' it anyway? The documentation says

> Open opens the named file for reading. If successful, methods on the
>   returned file can be used for reading; the associated file descriptor
>   has mode O_RDONLY. If there is an error, it will be of type
>   *PathError. [[reference](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Open)]

If the 'directory' is a 'file' is disputable but for me it looks a bit misleading. Is there any usage for that behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Reading" has more meanings, one of which is reading the contents of a file.

Another meaning is if the file denotes a directory, you may read its content, which is the list of the files / subfolders in it, using [`File.Readdir()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Readdir) or [`File.Readdirnames()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Readdirnames). This is perfectly valid for an opened file whose name denotes a directory.

Also you may do a lot more with an opened [`os.File`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File) even if it denotes a folder, e.g. call its [`File.Chdir()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Chdir) (exclusive for directories) or [`File.Chmod()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Chmod) methods, or get statistics about it using [`File.Stat()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Stat). I don't see why "opening" a folder should be disallowed. The wording in the doc may not be perfect (or it could be extended to mention this though).

Comment: Right, I missed the existence of the `Readdir()` method. It makes the idea clear. I guess it is just a bit counterintuitive for those who came to Go from other languages.

Comment: @Grief: it might be useful to know that opening a directory and using readdir is a POSIX interface, and not dependent on a particular language. Since Go has roots in C and unix systems, that's often a good place to look for direction.